# jQuery function not executing inside PHP foreach loop

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, foreach

I'm trying to generate a number of checkboxes for a filter panel that when checked will refresh a list of products taking a specific parameter into account.

In a foreach loop, I'm successfully creating the checkboxes by gathering the filter attributes from xml data called from an API

```
foreach ($attrib->attributeValues->attributeValue as $attribValue)
{
$attribValue = $attribValue->name;
$attribValueID = $attribValue[@id];

$BODY .= sprintf("<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"%s\" value=\"%s\" id=\"%s\" checked%s=\"checked\" /> %s ",
$attribClass, $attribValue, $attribValue, $attribValue, $attribValue);
```

Next, I'm testing a basic jQuery function with two simple alerts to insure that the functions are actually being called

```
$BODY .= "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
$BODY .= "alert('Hello world!');";
$BODY .= "$(\"#".$attribValue."\").change(function() {";
$BODY .= "var $input = $(this);";
$BODY .= "alert(\"".$attribValue."\");";
$BODY .= "}).change();</script>";
```

When I run this on the page, the rendered html source code definitely shows that the jQuery function is being generated (multiple times, one for each checkbox created), but I'm not seeing either of the alerts - the one outside the function, or the one inside. It's my first time working with jQuery - any thoughts? Thanks as always!

Edit: Sorry, here's the generated HTML source code for two checkboxes - this continues for all the checkboxes present, which are in the double digits.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Color" value="Black" id="Black" checkedBlack="checked" /> Black <script type="text/javascript">alert('Hello world!');$("#Black").change(function() {var  = $(this);alert("Black");}).change();</script>
<input type="checkbox" name="Color" value="Silver" id="Silver" checkedSilver="checked" /> Silver <script type="text/javascript">alert('Hello world!');$("#Silver").change(function() {var  = $(this);alert("Silver");}).change();</script>
```

Comment: did you see any JS error? where you are including jquery? And above all why you doing this in PHP?

Comment: I think you mean "When I run this on the page, the rendered html source code definitely shows that the jQuery function is being _generated_ (multiple times..." Because if the function was running you would be seeing the alerts and wouldn't note that you're determining that is being generated by looking at static code via View Source.

Comment: You **REALLY** need to look into using [HEREDOCs](http://php.net/heredoc). Beyond that, what does your actual generated html look like?

Comment: Will you paste the relevant generated HTML?

Comment: Can you please also add the output html of that code?

Comment: Sorry, thanks for the feedback - added in the generated HTML above in the post. There's no JS error - I'm doing it in the PHP because I need the javascript function to run everytime a checkbox is made in the PHP foreach loop.

Comment: The JS you are outputting is invalid. There is no JS error because it is a JQuery error which does not get reported. I will update my answer with the fix. give me a minute.

Comment: when i see string concatenation like it is done here I feel pukish.. please use [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Comment: another suggestion javascript is comfortable with ' (single quote) instead of double quote.. use that and avoid the escaping...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my updated fix.

```
$BODY .= "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
$BODY .= "$(document).ready(function(){";
$BODY .= "alert('Hello world!');";
$BODY .= "$(\"#".$attribValue."\").live('click',function() {";
$BODY .= "var \$input = $(this);";
$BODY .= "alert(\"".$attribValue."\");";
$BODY .= "}).click();});</script>";
```

you can see an example of this output in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/Zapjh/)

I did have to write in the `$(document).ready()` as well as escape the `$input` in php to ensure it is not rendered as a php string. I also changed the `.change()` to `.live('click',` and `.click()`

the live part will ensure dynamically loaded checkboxes are seen. I just prefer the click event, you can have it set to change if you prefer.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks - I tried that, and it doesn't seem to have had any effect, neither of the alerts are still showing up.

Comment: Also you may benefit from adding labels to your checkboxes.. again you can see them in my Fiddle. They give the ability to change the checkbox by clicking on the label.

Comment: Hey rlemon - thanks so much for the follow up. With that code change, the page now miraculously outputs two "Hello World" alerts, but still no alerts from within the function or any further Hello Worlds (there should be several as there are many more than two checkboxes). Any thoughts here?

Comment: Ok, you will have to post more code then. with the information you have given me this is the best I can do.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are overwriting `$attribValue` here: `$attribValue = $attribValue->name;` - you shoul dprobably use a different variable to store that value: `$myAttribValue = $attribValue->name;`

Comment: Thanks - caught that and fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use jQuery to overcomplicate this here.

Use this:

```
function filterToggle(element){
var elementII = document.getElementById(element)
if(elementII.checked){
alert("Checked");
}
else{
alert("Unchecked");
}
}
```

then add an onclick="filterToggle('%s')" to your checkboxes