# Javascript not recognizing initial checkbox value

Tags: javascript, checkbox, toggle

I'm trying to create a toggle function in Javascript for an HTML checkbox where if the checkbox is checked/unchecked, the javascript detects that with an if statement and executes an action accordingly (in this case, adding/removing a parameter to url and refreshing the page with a new set of results)

Right now, I'm just trying to test the functionality of the javascript toggle by having alerts pop up when the box is checked/unchecked.

Here's the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function filterToggle(attribName)
{
  var elementII = document.getElementById(attribName);
  if(elementII.checkedTag == "unchecked"){
     elementII.checkedTag = "checked";
     alert("checked");
  }
  else {
    elementII.checkedTag = "unchecked";
    alert("unchecked");
  }
}
</script>
```

And here's where the checkboxes are being created multiple times, inside a php foreach loop:

```
$BODY .= sprintf("<input type=\"checkbox\" onclick=\"filterToggle('%s')\" name=\"%s\" value=\"%s\" id=\"%s\" checkedTag=\"unchecked\"/> %s ",
                 $attribName, $attribName, $attribClass, $attribName, $attribName, $attribName);
```

So the idea here is the boxes should load on the page unchecked (which they are), and when I check them, an alert should say "checked", and when I uncheck, and alert should say "unchecked". Everything here works perfectly, *except* the fact that when I check the boxes now, they say "unchecked", and when I uncheck, they say "checked". So it seems the javascript is changing the value of the checkedTag attribute in the checkboxes and responding accordingly, *but* it's not recognizing the fact that the value of the checkbox is initially set to "unchecked", so that instead of setting it to unchecked and alerting "unchecked" when first clicked, as it's currently seemingly doing, it should set it to "checked" and alert "checked".

Any thoughts here? I can't figure out why it's not recognizing that initial value - tried double quotations around the checkedTag value, single quotations, no quotations...same result.

Here's some example output code in JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/intenex/s45JC/3/, with 3 checkboxes displaying the error described above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply don't add any `checked` attribute to the elements which should not be checked.

You are making it much more complicated than it is. Instead of adding a custom attribute, test the `checked` property of the DOM element:

Example:

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="filterToggle(this)" name="Below $110" value="Price Range" id="Below$110"  />
```

**JavaScript**

```
function filterToggle(element) {
  if(element.checked){
     alert("checked");
  }
  else {
     alert("unchecked");
  }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/s45JC/7/)

**Note:** Element `id`s cannot contain spaces.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/efortis/VqyLY/

The jQuery way

```
 $('input').change(function() {
   alert("Is checked? " + $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

**Edit**

Here's http://jsfiddle.net/efortis/s45JC/4/ your example working

```
$('input').change(function() {
   alert("Hello... " + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: I started out using jQuery and had a bunch of problems - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032748/jquery-function-not-executing-inside-php-foreach-loop

The issue is later down the road I need the jQuery to be specific to each checkbox as when each checkbox is checked a parameter unique to that checkbox will be inserted into the URL to reload a page of xml results, and I'm not sure how to best do this in jQuery. Any help would be greatly appreciated there, thanks!

Comment: See my edit, you can add a class the to inputs you want instead of all, then change `$('input')` to `$('.myClass')`.  You can see every individual checkbox returning its id, since I used `$(this)`.

Answer (score 1):

Where does the checkedTag come from? it is not part of the DOM. You should be using the checked attribute instead.

Comment: if I use the "checked" attribute, how do I make the checkboxes unchecked to begin with? with either checked="" or checked="unchecked", the checkboxes are still prechecked and the javascript doesn't work when adjusted accordingly - http://jsfiddle.net/intenex/s45JC/5/

Comment: No checked attribute in the tag. Checkboxes are unchecked by default. See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to include the var elementII = document.getElementById(element), as the element ID  isn't the same as the same as the element itself

```
function filterToggle(element){
var elementII = document.getElementById(element)
if(elementII.checked){
alert("Checked");
}
else{
alert("Unchecked");
}
}
```